# data pagination can't change codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

i'am create link 1 2 selanjutnya but if i click page '2' or 'selanjutnya' data can't change, always 10 data in page 1... why?

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url() . 'transaksi/index/';                   
$config['total_rows'] = $tot_hal->num_rows();
$config['per_page'] = $limit;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
echo $this->uri->total_segments();
$config['first_link'] = 'Awal';
$config['last_link'] = 'Akhir';
$config['next_link'] = 'Selanjutnya';
$config['prev_link'] = 'Sebelumnya';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$bc["paginator"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the results from the database based on the offset you are getting in the third segment of your function. This `$config['uri_segment'] = 3;` defines which segment holds the offset. Use this `$this->uri->segment(3)` as offset in your limit clause with `$limit`.

Answer (score 0):

You should count total pages, dont forget to add offset and limit data, also you should have model to call data by limit and offset, so your post->get per_page value decides whether what is next data. And load pagination from your view. Also i put first and last values from my lang file. Vice versa one day u could need to change language maybe.

[Codeigniter Pagination][1]

totalRows, find all data by count
listdata, find all data by limit offset
offset,decides where is offset by getting data from per_page get value.

```
> $data ['listvalues'] = $this->some_model->listdata ($limit, $offset);
> $this->load->library ( 'pagination' );  $data ['totalRows'] =
> $this->some_model->totalRows ( ); $limit = 10; $per_page = 10; $params
> = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc (); $offset = $this->input->get ( 'per_page' ); $config = array ( 'uri_segment' => 1,  'per_page' =>
> $per_page,  'total_rows' => $data ['totalRows'],  'base_url' =>
> site_url ( 'somepage/?' ),  'page_query_string' => TRUE, 
> 'full_tag_open' => '<ul>',  'full_tag_close' => '</ul>', 
> 'cur_tag_open' => '<li class="active"><a>',  'cur_tag_close' =>
> '</a></li>',  'prev_tag_open' => '<li>',  'prev_tag_close' => '</li>',
> 'next_tag_open' => '<li>',  'next_tag_close' => '</li>', 
> 'num_tag_open' => '<li>',  'first_link' => lang (
> 'links_pagination_first' ),  'last_link' => lang (
> 'links_pagination_last' ),  'last_tag_open' => '<li>', 
> 'last_tag_close' => '</li>',  'first_tag_open' => '<li>', 
> 'first_tag_close' => '</li>',  'first_link' => lang (
> 'links_pagination_first' ),  'last_link' => lang (
> 'links_pagination_last' ),  'num_links' => '10' );
> $this->pagination->initialize ( $config ); 
> $data ['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3; replace this by $config['uri_segment'] = $this->uri->rsegment(3);
```